# How to remove exactly normalize.css that comes from core (not anything else)?

Tags: 9

I tired

```
libraries-override:
  core/normalize:
    css:
      base:
        assets/vendor/normalize-css/normalize.css: false
        misc/normalize-fixes.css: false
```

or

```
libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        assets/vendor/normalize-css/normalize.css: false
        misc/normalize-fixes.css: false
```

These lines don't work

This is not a duplicate question because I am asking about a particular library, I did try the way mentioned in that answer and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your_theme_name.info.yml

```
stylesheets-remove:
  - '@stable/css/core/assets/vendor/normalize-css/normalize.css'
  - '@stable/css/core/normalize-fixes.css'
```

or

```
libraries-override:
  core/normalize: false
```